# How can I square values at alternating indices?

Tags: javascript

I have tried the code but not getting the correct output. I have written my code here but in this case I got the values correct but I did not get desired output.

Sample Input: `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`

Sample Output: `[ 1, 2, 9, 4, 25 ]`

```
"use strict";

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");

let inputString = "";
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on("data", (inputStdin) => {
  inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on("end", (_) => {
  inputString = inputString.trim().split("\n").map((str) => str.trim());
  main();
});

function readLine() {
  return inputString[currentLine++];
}

/* Please do not modify anything above this line */

function main() {
  const myArray = JSON.parse(readLine());
  
  /* i have written my code here but in this case i got the values correct but i did not get desired output */
  let square = [];
  const result =  myArray.map((value,index) => {
      if(index % 2 === 0) {
          square += value * value;
      }
      else {
          square += value;
      }
  });
  console.log(square);
}
```

Comment: You need to return computed value in `array#map` callback `if(index % 2 === 0) {  return value * value; } else { return value;}`

Comment: `square` is an array, so you should use `square.push(value)`, not `square += value`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use extra result variable just assign map results to a square variable.
Please try the below code.

```js
 const square =  myArray.map((value,index) => {
      if(index % 2 === 0) {
         return value * value;
      }
      else {
          return  value;
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const square = myArray.map((value, i) => {
  if (i % 2 === 0) return value ** 2;
  else return value;
});
console.log(square);
```

**Final Code:**

```js
"use strict";

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");

let inputString = "";
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on("data", (inputStdin) => {
  inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on("end", (_) => {
  inputString = inputString.trim().split("\n").map((str) => str.trim());
  main();
});

function readLine() {
  return inputString[currentLine++];
}

/* Please do not modify anything above this line */

function main() {
  const myArray = JSON.parse(readLine());
  
  const square = myArray.map((value, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) return value ** 2;
    else return value;
  });
  console.log(square);
}
```

Comment: I think you misread, the question is for alternating indices.

Comment: @RawleyFowler Yea, my bad, fixed the answer 